# AOSP build on custom device

Tags: android, android-source

I'm building `AOSP 4.2 Jelly Bean`.
Everything is ok when I build default `full-eng` configuration and run it on emulator.

I need to build custom device and run it (on `emulator` - for testing if it really works, and on real device).
When I create custom device based on `full_base.mk` file, and run it on `emulator` - `emulator` just hangs up on first screen with ANDROID text, and will not load at all.
I have `system.img, userdata.img, ramdisk.img` after building in out directory. Is this all what I need for building custom AOSP and run it on device? Can I run my build on emulator or just on real device?

Should I have something additional for building AOSP for real device: kernel, device drivers, etc.?

custom device folder files (device/my_company/my_product):

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

ifneq ($(filter my_product,$(TARGET_DEVICE)),)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
endif
```

**AndroidProducts.mk**

```
PRODUCT_MAKEFILES := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/full_myproduct.mk
```

**BoardConfig.mk**

```
TARGET_NO_BOOTLOADER := true
TARGET_NO_KERNEL := true

TARGET_ARCH := arm

TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT := armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT := generic
TARGET_CPU_ABI := armeabi-v7a
TARGET_CPU_ABI2 := armeabi

HAVE_HTC_AUDIO_DRIVER := true
BOARD_USES_GENERIC_AUDIO := true

# no hardware camera
USE_CAMERA_STUB := true

# Enable dex-preoptimization to speed up the first boot sequence
# of an SDK AVD. Note that this operation only works on Linux for now
ifeq ($(HOST_OS),linux)
  ifeq ($(WITH_DEXPREOPT),)
    WITH_DEXPREOPT := true
  endif
endif

# Build OpenGLES emulation guest and host libraries
BUILD_EMULATOR_OPENGL := true

# Build and enable the OpenGL ES View renderer. When running on the emulator,
# the GLES renderer disables itself if host GL acceleration isn't available.
USE_OPENGL_RENDERER := true
```

**full_myproduct.mk**

```
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/languages_full.mk)
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/full_base.mk)

#DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS :=
#PRODUCT_PACKAGES +=
#PRODUCT_COPY_FILES +=

PRODUCT_NAME := full_myproduct
PRODUCT_DEVICE := myproduct
PRODUCT_MODEL := Customized Android
PRODUCT_BRAND := Android
```

**vendorsetup.sh**

```
add_lunch_combo full_myproduct-userdebug
```

Comment: anything in logcat？ Usually there is some system service died in this case.

Comment: You said that you were building for the device http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/721860794/7_capacitive_screen_multi_touch_tablet.html Could you please tell where did you find drivers for this device?

Comment: drivers are provided by vendor. If you create custom ROM for specific device (not google. google device drivers are available for free), then you contact vendor and request device specific drivers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you have a good hold on the AOSP build system, especially on how to add new devices.

`full-eng` only targets the emulator. Usually you build custom `.img` for the device in question, as the hardware drivers play a big role in whether the device works or not.

For example, if you have a `grouper` or a `maguro`, you would end up building for that device instead of `full-eng`. `lunch` should list the additional devices as you add them to your `device/` and `vendor/` trees. Google provides the files necessary to build for the line of Nexus devices on their [website][https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers].

What is the custom device that you are building for? If your device is commercially sold, chances are someone on XDA is trying to port AOSP and friends (CM, AOKP, etc) to your device.

Even if your device isn't on XDA, chances are it has hardware common with a bunch of other devices that you can find on AOSP. At that point, you'd have to go cherry pick driver-specific bits of code, like wifi chipsets, sound devices, etc.

I don't have a good primer for building off the top of my head, but http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Main_Page should be fairly helpful to you. This wiki has improved a lot since its creation and now has a chockful of useful information.

Comment: I have to build for device http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/721860794/7_capacitive_screen_multi_touch_tablet.html. If I understand you right, for custom build not enough minimal preferences defined by me, but I need also specify and provide drivers in device/my_company/my_product folder?

Comment: drivers would be located in `vendor/my_company/my_product` folder, but yes. take a look at how CyanogenMod does it: https://github.com/TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_samsung

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some of the vendor's drivers.
goto: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers

download the appropriate drivers for the exact device. put the *.sh file in your aosp top directory. 
run each of the shell file and accept the terms.

then recompile the code!

Comment: I think this is solution. I build AOSP with Android 5.1.1, but there is problem with OpenGL (which i found in logcat).